# How refresh the page when scrolled to the bottom flutter web?

Tags: flutter, pull-to-refresh, flutter-listview, scrollable

I have a list view that displays the data fetched from the API. And I'd use the [pull_to_refresh_flutter3](https://pub.dev/packages/pull_to_refresh_flutter3) package to refresh the page when the page dragged upwards. It was working fine On the mobile. Now I want to implement it on the web. When the user scrolls to the bottom, the `RefreshIndicator()` should be triggered. How do I achieve this?

```
SmartRefresher(
                controller: homeViewModel.refreshRequestedTask,
                enablePullDown: false,
                enablePullUp: true,
                footer: const ClassicFooter(
                  loadStyle: LoadStyle.ShowWhenLoading,
                ),
                onLoading: () => homeViewModel.loadMoreRequestedTask(),
                child: ListView.builder(
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  itemCount: homeViewModel.taskList.length,
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                    return TaskCardView(
                      taskList: homeViewModel.taskList,
                      index: index,
                    );
                  },
                ),
              ),
```

Answer (score 0):

You can `FutureBuilder` to work smooth with `RefreshIndicator` .
OR you can use use  `StreamBuilder` which automatically update app when changes occur.
You just have to return `ListView.builder` in `builder:` property

Comment: It should not update automatically. The `RefreshIndicatior()` should only get trigger when I scroll and hit the bottom.

Comment: Then you can use `futurebuilder`, it is updated once  when the `build` method is called.So you can use `RefreshIndicatior` with it